# SPField not visible on default view when SPList created programatically

Tags: spfield, splist

I'm creating an SPList item programatically. Everything goes fine, I add a list, I add spfields to it.

```
SPList list = (SPList)oWeb.Lists[listName];

SPField libraryNameField = new SPField(list.Fields, "Library", Names.LIBRARY_NAME);
libraryNameField.Type = SPFieldType.Text;
libraryNameField.Required = true;
list.Fields.Add(libraryNameField);
```

But I encounter a problem. The fields are created, but not viewed on default view. What am I missing? How can I achieve that programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically add the column to the list view. For example,

```
//Get list object
SPList list = oWeb.Lists[listName];
//Get the view 
SPView defaultView = list.DefaultView;
//Add the desired fields
defaultView.ViewFields.Add(libraryNameField.Name);    
//Update the view
defaultView.Update();    
//Update the List -- Not entirely sure this step is necessary.
list.Update();
```